# PHP5.3 json_encode is outputting bad json

Tags: php, json

I am attempting to json_encode an array in php5.3.

```
json_encode($paperwork_info[0])
```

The result is bad json.  The array is as follows:

```
[paperwork_guid] => c5bfe512-908d-c513-5a5e-e3a2fbb5548b
[name] => recycle
[sections] => Array
    (
        [0] => header
        [1] => customer
        [2] => scope_bullets
        [3] => product
        [4] => signature
        [5] => installer
        [6] => order_data
    )

[data] => Array
    (
        [header] => Array
            (
                [image] => Array
                    (
                        [src] => recycle.png
                        [format] => float:left
                    )

            )

        [customer] => Array
            (
                [f_name] => TEST ONLY
                [l_name] => NEIMEIER
                [middle_name] => none
                [title] => none
                [address1] => 28 OEHMAN BLVD
                [address2] => 
                [address3] => 
                [zip] => 14225
                [city] => BUFFALO
                [state_abbrev] => NY
                [email_address] => DALE.NEIMEIER@INSTALLS.COM
                [phones] => Array
                    (
                        [alt] => 
                        [cell] => 
                        [work] => 
                        [home] => 7165551212
                    )

            )

        [scope_bullets] => Array
            (
                [sku_3001] => Array
                    (
                        [bullet_0] => Array
                            (
                                [paperwork_bullet_obj_guid] => 2ebefa96-6f6b-069e-e194-245d138b9845

                                [ordering] => 1
                                [bullet_text] => This is bullet point #1
                                [child_level] => 1
                                [formatting] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => Array
                                            (
                                                [start_word] => 2
                                                [num_words] => 0
                                                [tag] => b
                                                [href] => 
                                            )

                                        [1] => Array
                                            (
                                                [start_word] => 2
                                                [num_words] => 1
                                                [tag] => a
                                                [href] => http://www.cnn.com
                                            )

                                    )

                            )

                        [bullet_1] => Array
                            (
                                [paperwork_bullet_obj_guid] => 734db3f4-01a0-b025-9624-cc52a1845dff

                                [ordering] => 1
                                [bullet_text] => Sub-point #1.1
                                [child_level] => 2
                            )

                        [bullet_2] => Array
                            (
                                [paperwork_bullet_obj_guid] => ebf5ef02-906e-2005-e499-27eae2edefe9

                                [ordering] => 1
                                [bullet_text] => Sub point #1.1.1
                                [child_level] => 3
                            )

                        [bullet_3] => Array
                            (
                                [paperwork_bullet_obj_guid] => 447997c1-fd9c-25be-b9bf-39257009fb8b

                                [ordering] => 1
                                [bullet_text] => This is bullet point #2
                                [child_level] => 1
                            )

                        [bullet_4] => Array
                            (
                                [paperwork_bullet_obj_guid] => 5def2d9c-d322-788c-0afe-d13707004b97

                                [ordering] => 1
                                [bullet_text] => Sub point #2.1
                                [child_level] => 2
                            )

                        [bullet_5] => Array
                            (
                                [paperwork_bullet_obj_guid] => 84936151-65a3-bcca-951f-b69ff16d34ec

                                [ordering] => 2
                                [bullet_text] => Sub point #2.2
                                [child_level] => 2
                            )

                    )

                [sku_4405] => 
            )

        [product] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [model] => Paperwork Test abc123
                        [serial] => 777333
                        [weight] => 26
                        [size] => 
                        [width] => 
                        [height] => 32
                        [num_boxes] => 1
                        [product_name] => 
                        [sku] => 
                        [model_number] => 
                        [part_number] => 
                        [serial_number] => 
                        [cat_value] => Best Buy Equipment
                        [product] => 
                        [product_type] => 
                        [product_size] => 
                        [category] => 
                    )

            )

        [signature] => Array
            (
                [date] => 2016-06-15
                [need_customer] => 1
                [need_tech] => 1
                [need_store] => 
                [need_warehouse] => 
            )

        [installer] => Array
            (
                [anum] => 45455
                [inst_obj_guid] => fb91cf85-381c-b740-e063-775151743da2
                [phone] => (317) 519-0481
                [tech_f_name] => 
                [tech_l_name] => 
                [company_name] => ZICO LLC
                [email_address] => ZICOLLC@GMAIL.COM
            )

        [order_data] => Array
            (
                [assigned_date] => 2016-06-07 22:24:47-04
                [purchased_date] => 2016-06-06
                [creation_date] => 2016-06-06
                [install_date] => 2016-06-10
                [install_time] => 19:00:00
                [prescheduled_date] => 1969-12-31
                [prom_start_time] => 2016-06-10 08:06:00
                [prom_end_time] => 2016-06-10 11:06:00
                [client_order_id] => 12365478996325412
                [job_num] => 4043269
                [campaign_wkord_obj_guid] => a9a8cc0b-d7ef-ac0e-df61-dad41c023cb0
                [pos_obj_guid] => 096e38c2-55c3-80cf-0778-23f81f1cf2f6
                [inst_obj_guid] => fb91cf85-381c-b740-e063-775151743da2
                [client_obj_guid] => 247e893a-3ea4-c544-47b2-f23ff16017c6
                [ord_obj_guid] => ae55e034-d7d0-5d13-3dd3-22f99df8ead4
                [skus] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [job_type_obj_guid] => 8234ca2c-e40e-c48c-befc-7ceac5e9de32
                                [job_sku] => 3001
                                [client_sku] => 
                                [sku_name] => Site Survey
                            )

                        [1] => Array
                            (
                                [job_type_obj_guid] => a3f60c3b-ad3c-d828-9898-fa200edcd3cd
                                [job_sku] => 4405
                                [client_sku] => 
                                [sku_name] => Home Delivery
                            )

                    )

                [client_specific_data] => 
            )

    )
```

)

The resultant json string is as follows:

```
{"paperwork_guid":"c5bfe512-908d-c513-5a5e-e3a2fbb5548b","name":"recycle","sections":{"0":"header","1"
:"customer","2":"scope_bullets","3":"product","4":"signature","5":"installer","6":"order_data"},"data"
:{"header":{"image":{"src":"recycle.png","format":"float:left"}},"customer":{"f_name":"TEST ONLY","l_name"
:"NEIMEIER","middle_name":"none","title":"none","address1":"28 OEHMAN BLVD","address2":"","address3"
:null,"zip":"14225","city":"BUFFALO","state_abbrev":"NY","email_address":"DALE.NEIMEIER@INSTALLS.COM"
,"phones":{"alt":"","cell":"","work":"","home":"7165551212"}},"scope_bullets":{"sku_3001":{"bullet_0"
:{"paperwork_bullet_obj_guid":"2ebefa96-6f6b-069e-e194-245d138b9845","ordering":"1","bullet_text":"This
 is bullet point #1","child_level":"1","formatting":{"0":{"start_word":"2","num_words":"0","tag":"b"
,"href":""},"1":{"start_word":"2","num_words":"1","tag":"a","href":"http:\/\/www.cnn.com"}}},"bullet_1"
:{"paperwork_bullet_obj_guid":"734db3f4-01a0-b025-9624-cc52a1845dff","ordering":"1","bullet_text":"Sub-point
 #1.1","child_level":"2"},"bullet_2":{"paperwork_bullet_obj_guid":"ebf5ef02-906e-2005-e499-27eae2edefe9"
,"ordering":"1","bullet_text":"Sub point #1.1.1","child_level":"3"},"bullet_3":{"paperwork_bullet_obj_guid"
:"447997c1-fd9c-25be-b9bf-39257009fb8b","ordering":"1","bullet_text":"This is bullet point #2","child_level"
:"1"},"bullet_4":{"paperwork_bullet_obj_guid":"5def2d9c-d322-788c-0afe-d13707004b97","ordering":"1","bullet_text"
:"Sub point #2.1","child_level":"2"},"bullet_5":{"paperwork_bullet_obj_guid":"84936151-65a3-bcca-951f-b69ff16d34ec"
,"ordering":"2","bullet_text":"Sub point #2.2","child_level":"2"}},"sku_4405":null},"product":{"0":{"model"
:"Paperwork Test abc123","serial":"777333","weight":"26","size":null,"width":null,"height":"32","num_boxes"
:"1","product_name":null,"sku":null,"model_number":null,"part_number":null,"serial_number":null,"cat_value"
:"Best Buy Equipment","product":null,"product_type":null,"product_size":null,"category":null}},"signature"
:{"date":"2016-06-15","need_customer":true,"need_tech":true,"need_store":false,"need_warehouse":false
},"installer":{"anum":"45455","inst_obj_guid":"fb91cf85-381c-b740-e063-775151743da2","phone":"(317) 519-0481"
,"tech_f_name":null,"tech_l_name":null,"company_name":"ZICO LLC","email_address":"ZICOLLC@GMAIL.COM"
},"order_data":{"assigned_date":"2016-06-07 22:24:47-04","purchased_date":"2016-06-06","creation_date"
:"2016-06-06","install_date":"2016-06-10","install_time":"19:00:00","prescheduled_date":"1969-12-31"
,"prom_start_time":"2016-06-10 08:06:00","prom_end_time":"2016-06-10 11:06:00","client_order_id":"12365478996325412"
,"job_num":"4043269","campaign_wkord_obj_guid":"a9a8cc0b-d7ef-ac0e-df61-dad41c023cb0","pos_obj_guid"
:"096e38c2-55c3-80cf-0778-23f81f1cf2f6","inst_obj_guid":"fb91cf85-381c-b740-e063-775151743da2","client_obj_guid"
:"247e893a-3ea4-c544-47b2-f23ff16017c6","ord_obj_guid":"ae55e034-d7d0-5d13-3dd3-22f99df8ead4","skus"
:{"0":{"job_type_obj_guid":"8234ca2c-e40e-c48c-befc-7ceac5e9de32","job_sku":"3001","client_sku":null
,"sku_name":"Site Survey"},"1":{"job_type_obj_guid":"a3f60c3b-ad3c-d828-9898-fa200edcd3cd","job_sku"
:"4405","client_sku":null,"sku_name":"Home Delivery"}},"client_specific_data":""}}}
```

It appears as though new line feeds are being inserted randomly throughout the josn string.  I am not sure if it is just how firebug is outputting the string, but copying-and-pasting the string into jsonLINT produces errors.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you set your headers making it known that it is JSON data?

Comment: How are you calling your script? Is it trough ajax or something?

Comment: Yes, it is through ajax.  The option return type is set to json. I have tried to set the header to content-type: application/json as well.  UPDATE: the above is not done via ajax.  I just outputted the array in a print_r and the json string in an echo and copied the results directly from firebug console.  When I execute the code using an ajax call I get the bad json string.

Comment: Straight after json_encode, run json_decode and see if you get a result. At the moment it sounds like the issue is most likely the copy + paste.

Comment: Thanks, Jon - I don't know what I didn't think of that!  it does look like it is a copy and paste problem.  Still, my ajax fails, but the problem must be in how I am executing the call.  Thanks for the review

Comment: Np. Good luck with the rest :)